# Php equivalent of substr and strpos in Python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, substring, strpos

I try to transform this **php**-function into **Python**:

```
function trouveunebrique($contenu, $debut, $fin) {
  $debutpos = strpos($contenu, $debut);
  $finpos = strpos($contenu, $fin, $debutpos);
  if ($finpos == 0) {
    $finpos = strlen($contenu);
  }
  $nbdebut = strlen($debut);
  if ($debutpos > 0) {
    $trouveunebrique = substr($contenu, ($debutpos + $nbdebut), ($finpos - $debutpos - $nbdebut));
  } 
  else {
    $trouveunebrique = "";
  }

  return (trim($trouveunebrique));
}
```

I searched [here](http://www.php2python.com/) but i could't find the solution.
I also tried this:

```
   def trouveunebrique(contenu, debut, fin)
        debutpos = haystack.find(contenu, debut)
        finpos = haystack.find(contenu, fin)
        if (finpos == 0)
            finpos = len(contenu)
        nbdebut = len(debut)
        if (debutpos > 0):
            trouveunebrique = substr(contenu, (debutpos + nbdebut), (finpos - debutpos - nbdebut))
        else:
            trouveunebrique = ""
        return trouveunebrique.strip()
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @spectras i want to transform my Php-function to Python

Comment: Be it Python or PHP, still it's super ugly ;) If you feel like refactoring, I'd recommend regular expressions.

Comment: He did ask a valid (although implicit) question: _How to transform this PHP function to Python?_ Everything's OK. This question **can be answered**!

Comment: @zx485: The OP could rephrase his question to explain what is wrong with his  solution, and ask how to fix it.  If he did, it would be a clear, on-topic question.  Some kind soul might even suggest a better way.   He could also remove his solution, and ask how to translate the code.  If he did, it would be a clear, *off-topic* question.  SO is.not a code-translation service.  As the question now stands, it is unclear if he wants a new solution or a fix to his solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get substrings in Python (and any subsequences for that matter) use [slice notation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), which is similar to indexing but contains at least one colon between brackets:

```
>>> "Hello world"[4:7]
'o w'
>>> "Hello world"[:3]
'Hel'
>>> "Hello world"[8:]
'rld'
```

You figured out strpos() equivalent already: [str.find()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) method on string objects. Also note that you can provide an additional index to it like in your PHP function:

```
debutpos = contentu.find(debut)
# ...
finpos = contenu.find(fin, debutpos)
```

It returns -1 when substring is not found. Otherwise, it behaves like PHP equivalent.

Comment: thanks, i can do this for substringin, and for strpos what i can do ?

Comment: Checkout my answer update. I recommend the linked tutorial on basic Python features. It really pays off reading it.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood correctly, you want to find a substring in `contenu` starting by `debut` and finish by `fin` ?

So if you set up

```
>>> str   = "abcdefghi"
>>> debut = "bcd"
>>> fin   = "hi"
```

You want to do :

```
>>> trouveunebrique(str, debut, fin)
bcdefghi
```

If that's the case, what you are looking for is `(string).find` which behave like your `strpos`

So your method will looks like this :

```
def trouveunebrique(contenu, debut, fin):
  indice_debut = contenu.find(debut)
  indice_fin = contenu.find(fin)
  return contenu[indice_debut : indice_fin + len(fin)]
```

Or in short :

```
def trouveunebrique(contenu, debut, fin):
 return contenu[contenu.find(debut):contenu.find(fin) + len(fin)]
```

Also since you want your `fin` to be after your `debut`, the following should work :

```
def trouveunebrique(contenu, debut, fin):
  indice_debut = contenu.find(debut) # find the first occurence of "debut"
  indice_fin = contenu[indice_debut:].find(fin) # find the first occurence of "fin" after "debut"
  return contenu[indice_debut : indice_debut + indice_fin + len(fin)]
```

Comment: my function in Php works, but your suggestion return empty string

Comment: Updated, I forgot the + `len(fin)` (to add `fin` in the substring). Also now `fin`is always after `debut`